# how do i get all the similar documents without any search terms

Tags: search, lucene

i need to develop a search application , where many documents are indexed with different fields and a id field which is unique for each of the document . Fields are not stored just indexed except for id field

i need to find out for each document , the documents similar to this, here all i have is unique id field of current document , i dont have any other fields of current document to form Terms and query the index for finding similar documents like current one.

How do i do this ?  any help greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the simplest way to do this is to use Solr, and use Solr's [MoreLikeThisHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis). 
You can use a query like`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=unique_id:2722&mlt=true&mlt.fl=manu,cat&mlt.mindf=1&mlt.mintf=1&fl=id,score`

Comment: hey yeah thanx i recollect now , there is complete worked example of "MoreLikethis " in Manning Lucene in action book , thanq very much , let me try that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control over how these documents are indexed?  You can index with term vectors, and at query time, look up the term vector for the document, construct a query using the terms, and submit the query.

Comment: yes i have access to indexing too , i would try this , thanq !